# Flutter: ChipList options in horizontal ListView

Tags: flutter, scroll, chips

When we create a ChipList in Flutter, when the chips are overflowed, the next chip will appear depends on the verticalDirection attribute (could be up/down).

But is it possible to put the chips in a horizontal ListView? So when it overflows, user can scroll to the right to see the next chips.

Here is the code part for the Filter Chip:

```
  Widget _SearchBody() => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            child: FormBuilder(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
  ...
  ...
  Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              child:
                  Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text('Tipe bahan bakar')),
                FormBuilderFilterChip(
                  name: 'Fuel',
                  decoration: InputDecoration(),
                  spacing: 8,
                  options: [
                    FormBuilderFieldOption(
                        value: 'diesel', child: Text('Diesel')),
                    FormBuilderFieldOption(
                        value: 'hybrid', child: Text('Hybrid')),
                    FormBuilderFieldOption(
                        value: 'bensin', child: Text('Bensin')),
                    FormBuilderFieldOption(
                        value: 'listrik', child: Text('Listrik')),
                  ],
                ),
              ]),
            ),
  ...
  ...
```

Note: I use the [Flutter Form Builder package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder).

And here is the result below, as can be seen the 4th chips is shown at below of the other 3 chips, while what I want is the **4th chips is to be still at the right of 3rd chips, and user can just scroll to the right at that screen part to see the 4th chips**:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufqBv.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ListView with horizontal axis to make a list of chips scrollable to the right.

Just do it like this:

```
ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: [
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
      Chip(
        label: Text("1"),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

This is it. The chips don't wrap anymore.

If you are already wrapping this ListView with a horizontal ListView you can just use a Column (just like you can't put two regular ListViews inside each other).

I hope I was able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  children: chips.map((chip) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0), // Adjust horizontal spacing between chips
      child: ChoiceChip(
        label: Text(
          chip,
          style: TextStyle(color: BrandColors.kBlack), // Chip Font
        ),
        selected: _selectedChips.contains(chip),
        onSelected: (_) => _toggleChip(chip),
        backgroundColor: BrandColors.kLight, // Chip Background Color
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

[show picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qQIB.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).